Theoretically, how low voltage can we go to reduce power consumption in CPUs?
My understanding is that power consumption of a CPU is approximately given by \$C\cdot V^2\cdot f\$ (capacitance, voltage, frequency).
Suppose we wanted to design a CPU so as to reduce CPU energy-consumption-per-instruction-cycle as much as possible, disregarding power consumption of other components. Suppose we are willing to accept very low frequencies in return for the efficiency.
Can we design a CPU with arbitrarily low voltage, and still get power efficiency gains according to the above formula (assuming we also reduce the frequency proportionally)?
My guess would be that we somehow can't.
Is there some low-voltage regime at which the above formula breaks down?

Some CPUs include more than one voltage rail: e.g., an I/O voltage and a CPU core voltage rail. Some of the CPU core voltage rails have a range over which they can operate and the choice impacts the available frequency of operation of the core. For example GTL can operate anywhere from about 1.2 V down to something like 0.3 or 0.4 V. Some CPUs are designed to allow their power supply to be programmed by the BIOS (or other means) to select the desired operating core voltage. There is always both a static part (not affected by freq) and a dynamic part (affected by freq) to the dissipation.

@periblepsis, interesting. But my question would still be, how low could chip designers make the lowest voltage, suppose they were to aim solely for energy efficiency and would accept very low frequencies, and what physical principles determines the lowest that they could get? I assume that the static dissipation is still also determined by voltage squared?

No one is going to write the book. I won't try. But a segue would be to study the behind-the-scenes design that took place for the MSP430 (before TI purchased the German company developing it.) It was designed specifically for energy efficiency, as it was supposed to be used on residential power metering and customers don't like the idea of having to pay for the power company's own meters. Elements to your question, though, are actually quite broad and involve many many issues. There's no bright line. If there were, there would be no innovation as the answer would be obvious to all.

Undervolting means to run it lower than specs. If you run below the specs the cpu operation cannot be guaranteed at all, so isn't the answer "none"?

@periblepsis, but what is stopping a chip designer from just taking an existing chip design and saying: set voltage to 0.001V, and in order to still get the same reliability, set frequency to 1Hz. Would this work? (I know it would be a commercially useless device, I'm just trying to understand the physical principles)

@Justme, fair point. Why is there a lowest voltage at all though? why can't we just decrease the voltage indefinitely so long as we also decrease the frequency proportionally?

@user56834 Your semiconductors will stop working because you can't make transistors that turn on and off with any arbitrarily low voltage and achieve proper operations at 0V that take infinity to happen. Also at lower voltage, the transistors turn less on, spend longer time in transitions and are halfway on so you get more wasted shoot-through current than charging capacitances. It's always a trade-off where you want to waste the energy and how.

@user56834 See my answer as an expansion of Justme's comment as to why FETs cannot run with arbitrarily low voltage.

MOSFETs at room temperature can change their channel resistance by one decade for every 60 mV of gate voltage - at best. This value of the subthreshold slope is called the "thermionic limit" and is a consequence of fundamental thermodynamics for FETs. If you want good efficiency, then channel leakage should be minimized, so you might want to consider an ON/OFF ratio of channel resistance of at least 5-6 orders of magnitude. This will put the minimum gate voltage at 300-360 mV.
So naively, one could aim for a factor of ~10 improvement of task energy, with today's manufacturing technology and architectures. However possible frequencies would be really low.
Therefore, logic manufacturers realize that lowering the gate voltage for MOSFETs is not a very good way to improve task energy. Instead, I think the interest lies in other computing elements to replace MOSFET-based ALUs. Some concepts deviate very far from boolean CMOS logic, but other concepts also exist to replace only the digital switches with something else that does not suffer from the thermodynamic limit of the subthreshold slope. One thing that comes to mind are Tunnel FETs, but there are also other concepts which you can find if you search for transistors with enhanced subthreshold slope. With such technologies, one could reduce supply voltage quite a bit further, maybe squeezing another order of magnitude out of task energy improvement.

There is also near and sub-treshold computing with more or less normal mosfets. Never used them, but Ambiq says their ARM cores can run at less than 0.5V, presumably at a very low clock rate.

@user1850479 Yeah, what I am alluding to in my answer is sub-threshold computing. Above the "threshold", there is no "subthreshold slope".


Suppose we wanted to design a cpu so as to reduce cpu energy-consumption-per-instruction-cycle as much as possible,

We do that already all the time: most processors are limited by their ability to get the heat they produce out of the silicon die. So, optimization for minimizing the power consumption per computation is what you need to do, anyways. Just to give you an idea, the Jupiter high-performance computer ("supercomputer", hate that term) of the research lab in Jülich) does some 66 GFlops/W = 6.6·1010 (floating point operations)/s/(J/s) = 6.6·1010 (floating point operations)/J, or roughly 15 picojoule per floating point operation. (that is very little.)
But you're right, that's in conflict with getting high computation out of it.
There's a physical limit on how little work you can put in a single computational operation. It's called Landauer's principle. It derives, in the end, from computation changing the entropy of a system and hence, due to the conservation of impulse on a fundamental level, needing energy to do that.
So, erasing a single bit will necessarily yield
$$W=k_\text{B} T \ln 2$$
in energy (conversely, since that energy needs to get into that system, defining one will need you to add that amount of energy to the system.), where

\$k_\text{B}\$ is the Boltzmann constant (which you also know from the thermal voltage term in the Shockley diode equation, which you must have come across in your research on low power semiconductor engineering), and
\$T\$ the absolute temperature.

By the way, nothing says this will be achievable by computers running things strictly in "instruction cycles". It seems rather unlikely to me that that's the case, but I'm not familiar enough with the field to tell you about the actual details on limits of clocked systems. I'm a humble electrical engineer with a bit of background in information theory; this is hardcore statistical mechanics
Practically, we're currently multiple orders of magnitude above this, but you asked for a theoretical bound; and this is the one fundamental theoretical bound that any classical computer (anything that you could call "CPU" since it processes instructions) could achieve. Quantum computers might get lower than this for computations, but there's a reason why we speak of quantum computers and not processors.

just because there is a lower bound on the energy required doesn't mean there ISN'T an additional even higher lower bound that prevents us with current technology from just setting the voltage very low and additionally setting the frequency low to compensate. What is preventing this?

@user56834 are you asking for theoretical bounds or practical bounds? Because you literally just an hour ago said you were looking for theoretical bounds.

@user56834 and yes, there might be even higher theoretical lower bounds that we don't know. That is normal; finding new bounds is what is called scientific progress, and it's made every day. There's not many things where we have a proof for a lower bound for something, and a proof that this lower bound is also achievable.

I am looking for theoretical understanding, yes. But just because there is some very low lower bound doesn't mean that it gives the understanding relevant to a particular situation. If I ask you "theoretically what's the heaviest load that an ideal bridge of design X can carry?" a reasonable answer ISN'T to say "it must be smaller than about 150 solar masses, because otherwise it will collapse into a black hole". It's true, but doesn't clarify the question. I feel similarly about the landauer's limit in this case... (not to say it isn't an interesting answer by the way)

@user56834 but the thing is that you're asking this from an observational height that doesn't allow anyone really go into the details. I can tell you about bandgaps and thermal voltages, but that's so obvious to anyone who's had a basic education in semiconductors that they wouldn't have asked your question "can I go arbitrarily low" in the first place. I can't give you an intro to solid-state physics and basics of semiconductors – takes university students two full-time years of studying probability theory, physics, basics of electrical circuits and material science to arrive there, and then

it's still half of two heavy full-semester lectures with multiple hours a week (+ home prep) to get you where you'd say "oh, yeah, of course there's a the limit that your bandgap needs to be at least as large as the thermal voltage, else there can't be semiconducting behaviour", and then the next question would become "OK, if temperature sets a limit, can we do this supercooled" and then we get into the physics of superconductors and semiconductor junctions at cryogenic temperatures, and that's another can of worms.

And in the end you'd still be "OK, that's not practical anymore", and then we'd have the same discussion, but after me writing a relatively solid book on the matter (which I'm honestly not qualified to do, so you'd need to find someone extremely specialized with the spare time to give a private education to you: not likely).

Assuming that you reduce frequency to a very small value, there is a minimum voltage below which the logic cells like NAND, NOR, etc will just not toggle or will take forever to toggle. This will be the threshold voltage of the NMOS and PMOS transistors.

Which supply voltages the CPU can handle is already specified by its datasheet, but modern CPUs do not use that voltage internally. Instead they have a built-in step down regulator and run something like 1.8V or even lower internally.
However, fiddling around with voltage levels will only have a marginal effect on power consumption. The most important aspects are to implement a sleep schedule as well as keeping the clock speed as low as possible.
A common mistake is to only look at the current consumption while asleep vs the current consumption while active. This is a poor metric - what you should instead be looking at is current consumption over time required to perform a certain task. An AVR is for example likely far more current thirsty than a Cortex M0 with the same clock speed. Because even though the AVR probably has a significantly lower consumption asleep, it stays awake hundreds or maybe thousands times longer when performing the same calculation/executing the same C code as the Cortex M - thanks to the CPU inefficiency.

My apologies, my question was a bit unclear. My intended question was how low can we get in principle, not how low can I actually get as a consumer facing the design constraints of existing chips.

@user56834 Code efficiency matters for that as well. CPUs are meant to be slightly more than a fancy square wave generator.

Modern CPUs as used in computers and mobile devices are a good bit lower than 1.8 V internally. The CPU in the laptop I'm typing this on (a 9th gen i7) currently has a core voltage jumping between 0.615 V and 1.17 V as it modulates ts clock frequency.

@Hearth Hence "or even lower".

This may be of interest: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_circuit
M. P. Frank, R. W. Brocato, B. D. Tierney, N. A. Missert, A. H. Hsia, Reversible Computing with Fast, Fully Static, Fully Adiabatic CMOS, http://www.arxiv.org/abs/2009.00448 also looks like a promising read.
In the same way that an RF amplifier can produce output at frequencies far above the RL*Coss cutoff (by way of resonating that capacitance with an inductance), a CMOS logic circuit can be designed so that, with various transmission gates contingent on each others' values, all gate and junction capacitances can be sequentially sunk to a phase-shifted (or harmonic) set of oscillating reference clock signals; each signal therefore pushes around a generous total capacitance, but capacitance is a conservative element and, using a reactive drive circuit (i.e. inductors and switching), low-loss operation can be obtained.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing is a related topic: likely, adiabatic circuits will be reversible (or, down to a modest number of isolator/regenerator stages that would need to be inverted), i.e. reverse the clock sequence and the computation simply flows backwards.  The symmetry has obvious physical appeal: a reversible (thermodynamic) process is also a conservative one; here, power dissipation comes down to leakage currents and phasing errors.
Major downsides include the complexity of such logic families, and the resulting poor layout density.  On a planar process, the power savings isn't all that important from a feasibility standpoint: a regular (lossy) CMOS circuit is perfectly viable, as we have it today after all.  Building an adiabatic circuit in a planar process, will take up tons of die area for not much computation, and sure the power dissipation could be extremely low, but the cost of that logic is massive, and even accounting for a full extended product life cycle, it will be hard to justify the production cost.  Particularly as other power consumption in a device will remain unavoidable: a light-emitting display, or a WiFi radio, for example.
Conversely, the power savings would show its value in a deeply-layered or even volumetric construction, but we can't do that economically yet.  The primary barriers here are: maintaining crystal orientation on subsequent layers; and printing subsequent layers at all, while managing all the connections through such a construction.  Perhaps such logic could be built at even more substantial speed penalty, using amorphous or polycrystalline semiconductors, and the clock speed is made up for by sheer volume (the current trend/hype for neural networks might be a prime application for such architecture: the logical computation itself doesn't need to be very fast, if the process is embarrassingly parallel enough; the effective clock rate of the human brain is at most some 100s Hz).  But even given a well-characterized and, not just viable but economically proven and important, application, actually constructing such a massive multilayered or volumetric device in mass production boggles the mind.
I suppose it's even possible that, given the manufacturing difficulties of such a technology, quantum systems are either competitive, or perhaps even come to dominate, at some point in the future; the main downside is, unless an extremely clever system is devised with strong isolation from room-temperature interference, quantum computers will continue to require extremely powerful refrigeration to operate, which tends to dominate overall power consumption.  I suppose, as an example of technology by itself, "but for" the low ambient temperature requirement, quantum computing is also a meaningful (if yet far from practical) example.

The minimum voltage that can be used for the logic is determined by factors such as the threshold voltage of the devices and the noise margin required to avoid a logic one and zero being misinterpreted.
Modern fabrication techniques currently allow down to about 400mV supply voltage to be used and as feature sizes reduce the minimum voltage tends to go down.
As the voltage lowers the speed of operation reduces but for devices where power consumption is critical (such as cell-phones) dynamically manage the voltage so that it is reduced when power consumption is critical and raised when performance is critical. These supply voltage changes can occur many times per second.
